# Print many variables at a once in R

Tags: r, object

I have many variables loaded from multiple files (with `source(file)`) and I want to display its values one by one.

Example:
Name of the variables : `mu1`, `mu2`, `mu3`, `mu4`. 
I want to print them one by one with a simple R command.

Edit : my variables are not string:

```
    > mu1
                 pvalue
{}              0.000000
{1}             0.054782
{2}             0.528427
{1,2}           0.416791
```

Now I have 500 other variables (mu1...m500) to print.

Comment: Please share what you've tried.  Otherwise, we don't know what you mean by "print" them... `lapply(ls(), get)`?

Comment: Or save them all in a `list`

Comment: Why downvoting the question? What's wrong with it? Is it ill-posed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mget` to get the content of multiple variables at once.

```
vars <- c("mu1", "mu2", "mu3", "mu4") # names of the variables
```

You can also get the variables' names with `ls`:

```
vars <- ls(pattern = "^mu\\d+")
```

The above pattern returns the names of all variables staring with `mu` followed by at least one digit.

Use `mget` to get the variables:

```
mget(vars)
```

This returns a list that is printed (in interactive mode).

An example:

```
> mu1 <- 1:3
> mu2 <- matrix(0, 2, 2)
> mu3 <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = c("x", "y"))
> mu4 <- list(1, 2, 3)
> 
> vars <- c("mu1", "mu2", "mu3", "mu4")
> mget(vars)
$mu1
[1] 1 2 3

$mu2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

$mu3
  a b
1 1 x
2 2 y

$mu4
$mu4[[1]]
[1] 1

$mu4[[2]]
[1] 2

$mu4[[3]]
[1] 3
```

Comment: @Bill What are the names of the variables? Are they all starting with `mu`?

Comment: Yes, they are starting with mu (mu1 -> mu500)

Comment: @Bill I cannot reproduce the problem. You can get all variables' names with `vars <- ls(pattern = "^mu\\d+")`.

Comment: Then do this `mget(ls()[grep('mu',ls())])`

Comment: isn't possible with a for loop? something like mu$i (i:1->500)?